# Inherited field can not be autoIncremented Room Android

Tags: android, android-room

I have an issue where `autoGenerate` is not working on an inherited field in my Entity class.

In my project I have created a `base class` which has an `id` field already added to it. This base class is then used by every Entity so I can work with generics and such. Everything seems to work perfectly until I add the `autoGenerate` to the id field of an Entity. (FYI: this was working in version 2.2.6, but in 2.3.0 this breaks and results in this issue.)

The BaseEntity class

```
interface BaseEntity {
    val id: Any
}
```

The specific Entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = DBConstants.FOOD_ENTRY_TABLE_NAME)
data class FoodEntry(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    override val id: Int = 0,
    var amount: Float,
    var date: Long,
    var meal: Meal
) : BaseEntity
```

If I do something like this it works (but it's not what I need)

```
@Entity(tableName = DBConstants.FOOD_ENTRY_TABLE_NAME)
data class FoodEntry(
    override val id: Int = 0,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var someOtherId: Int = 0,
    var amount: Float,
    var date: Long,
    var meal: Meal
) : BaseEntity
```

As far as I can see this is only a problem when you wish to `autoGenerate` an inherited field.

Anybody else have seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I can see this is only a problem when you wish to autoGenerate an inherited field.

The same behaviour happens if you just have @PrimaryKey or if you define the id column as a primary key.

The issue is that Room interprets the **Int** as a Type of **int** (in the underlying Java code (perhaps a bug, *you may wish to raise an issue* )). Room if it considers the Type as **int** as opposed to **Int** treats the 0 default value differently.

1. In case of Type **Int** with a 0 then Room doesn't attempt to specify a value if it is a for a primary key column and thus allows SQLite to assign a value.

   - e.g. SQL along the lines of INSERT INTO the_table (amount,date,meal) VALUES(the_amount, the_date, the_meal);
2. If the Type is **int** then the value is always specified so the 0's will result in UNIQUE constrain conflicts.

   - e.g. SQL along the lines of INSERT INTO the_table  VALUES(0,the_amount, the_date, the_meal);

     - as the column list is omitted ALL columns need a value

**Possible Fix**

If you instead used

```
interface BaseEntity {
    val id: Any?
}
```

with :-

```
@PrimaryKey
override val id: Int? = null,
```

- generated java has :-
- ```
  _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food (id INTEGER, amount REAL NOT NULL, date INTEGER NOT NULL, meal TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))");
  ```

or :-

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
override val id: Int? = null,
```

- generated java has :-
- ```
    _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, amount REAL NOT NULL, date INTEGER NOT NULL, meal TEXT NOT NULL)");
  ```

then no attempt is made to insert the **id** value and SQLite assigns the value.

- in SQLite terms

**Alternative Fix**

If you use the original **BaseEntity** then you could insert using a Query where you exclude the **id** column and thus allow it to be generated.

e.g. you could have :-

```
@Query("INSERT INTO food (amount,date,meal) VALUES(:amount,:date,:meal)")
fun insertFE(amount: Float, date: Long, meal: String): Long
```

but that doesn't insert using a FoodEntry object so you could then have (dependant upon the above) :-

```
fun insertFE(FoodEntry: FoodEntry): Long {
    return insertFE(FoodEntry.amount,FoodEntry.date,your_type_converter(FoodEntry.meal))
}
```

- obviously your_type_converter would be changed accordingly

---

**About `autoGenerate`** *(AUTOINREMENT in SQLite)*

`autogenerate = true` does not noticeably effect the internally generated value until you reach the maximum allowed value (9223372036854775807). If autogenerate = true is coded and the last value was the 9223372036854775807  the next insert will result in a an SQLITE_FULL error and an exception.

If `autoGenerate = false` is coded or autoGenerate  is not specified then then SQLite will, if 9223372036854775807 has been assigned (and the row still exists), attempt to allocate an unassigned value between 1 and 9223372036854775807 which would likely succeed as it's basically impossible to have 9223372036854775807 rows.

- note that if any row has been assigned a negative value then the range is extended.
- of course specifying Int or int imposes a much lower restriction outside of SQLite. Really id's should be Long or long.

`autoGenerate= true` means that the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is included in the column definition. This is a constraint that says that when the value is determined by SQLite that the value must be greater than any value that either exists or has been used.

To ascertain this AUTOINCREMENT uses an internal table namely sqlite_sequence to store the last assigned/determined value. Having the additional table and having to access and maintain the table has overheads.

SQLite https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html  has as it's first sentence :- **The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.**

Comment: I'm not sure if we wish the field to be nullable, but we'll investigate further, thank you for the information. In case I wish to raise an issue, where would this best be done, do you know?

Comment: @ChristianoBolla null isn't passed as a value to the database instead Room omits the value from the list of values (also omitting the primary key column as they are paired i.e. as per the SQL shown in the alternative insert query).  The same action as specifying 0 when autogenerate=true is coded. You can raise issues by using Help/Submit Feedback. Of course the **alternative** fix in the answer can be used with either. That is it bypasses Room's basic handling if `integer primary key`. The only issue with this is that you then cannot use a specific id value.